# Export a Spark Dataframe (pyspark.pandas.Dataframe) to Excel file from Azure DataBricks

Tags: python, pandas, azure, pyspark, databricks

I'm struggling with the export of a pyspark.pandas.Dataframe to an Excel file.

I'm working on an Azure Databricks Notebook with Pyspark.
My goal is to read a csv file from Azure Data Lake Storage container and store it as a Excel file on another ADLS container.

I'm finding so many difficulties related to performances and methods.
pyspark.pandas.Dataframe has a built-in **to_excel** method but with files larger than 50MB the commands ends with time-out error after 1hr (seems to be a well known [problem](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python//reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html#pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.to_excel)).

Following you can find an example of code. It ends by saving the file on the DBFS (there are still problems integrating the to_excel method with Azure) and then I move the file to the ADLS.

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps
spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.account.key.{storage_account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net", storage_account_key)

reference_path = f'abfss://{source_container_nae}@{storage_account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/{file_name}'

df = ps.read_csv(reference_path, index=None)

df.to_excel(file_name, sheet_name='sheet')
```

pyspark.pandas.Dataframe is the suggested method by Databricks in order to work with Dataframes (it replaces koalas) but I can't find any solution to my problem, except converting the dataframe to a *normal* pandas one.

Can please someone help me?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE

Some more information of the whole pipeline.

I have a DataFactory pipeline that reads data from Azure Synapse, elaborate them and store them as csv files in ADLS. I need DataBricks because DataFactory does not have a native sink Excel connector!
I know that I can use instead Azure Functions or Kubernetes, but I started using DataBricks hoping that it was possible...

Comment: Why save such a large file in Excel format?

Comment: Well, because we have this constraint on the integration

Comment: hi @walzer91,Do you want to write an excel file only using Pandas dataframe?

Comment: Databricks is only used to read the csv and save a copy in xls? What will trigger Databricks? Are you using Data Factory?

Comment: Thanks to both, I've added some information on the question about the complete pipeline!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to the problem with the pyexcelerate package:

```
from pyexcelerate import Workbook

df = # read your dataframe

values = df.columns.to_list() + list(df.values)
sheet_name = 'Sheet'

wb = Workbook()
wb.new_sheet(sheet_name, data=values)
wb.save(file_name)
```

In this way Databricks succeed in elaborating a 160MB dataset and exporting to Excel in 3 minutes.

Let me know if you find a better solution!

Answer (score 0):

Hm.. it looks like you are reading the same file and saving to the same file.

can you change

```
df.to_excel(file_name, sheet_name='sheet')
```

to

```
df.to_excel("anotherfilename.xlsx", sheet_name='sheet')
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer!
Actually I'm reading the input csv file using an URI that points to the ADLS with the abfss protocol and I'm writing the output Excel file on the DBFS, so they have the same name but are located in different storages.

Answer (score -2):

You should not convert a big spark dataframe to pandas because you probably will not be able to allocate so much memory.
You can write it as a csv and it will be available to open in excel:

```
df.to_csv(path=file_name, num_files=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to have an Excel file, .xlsx

Comment: That should be easy to convert once you have the csv. If you have access to python or excel and enough resources it should take you a minute. I don't really know any other way to save as xlsx.

Comment: I agree with you but I tried with a 3 nodes cluster, each node with 14GB of RAM and 6 cores, and still stucks after 1 hour with a file of 150MB :(